# Elasticsearch filter by several geo_points with different weights

Tags: elasticsearch, geo

I have a number of documents that, apart from other fields, have a number of `geo_point`s associated with them. I want to find all documents that are associated with a particular city. To that end, I also have an index of cities, I search it first and get a list of coordinates with the `_score`s from that search. Now I want to pass that data to the document search and multiply the score of the found documents by the corresponding city score.

Assuming the first query returns a list of tuples like `[(city_coords, city_score), (...)]`, I want to build the query to the document index using the `function_score` and the `functions` array with each city as a separate function with its separate score.

However, when I construct the query in its simplest form, it fetches all the documents in my index. Here's what the query I have made:

```
{
    'query': {
        'function_score': {
            'functions': [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "1km",
                            "distance_type": "plane",
                            "points": city_coords
                        },
                    },
                    'weight': city_score
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? How do I get only the documents that are associated with that particular city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't specify a query in your `function_score` part, Elastic assume a match_all query. So it returns all documents and add a boost for the documents near the selected queries.

You should add a specific query in your function_score part that will filter out any document that is not near enough of the selected cities. Something like

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "geo_distance": {
                        "distance": "1km",
                        "distance_type": "plane",
                        "points": city_coords1
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "geo_distance": {
                        "distance": "1km",
                        "distance_type": "plane",
                        "points": city_coords2
                    }
                  },
                  ... and so on
                ]
              }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "1km",
                            "distance_type": "plane",
                            "points": city_coords
                        },
                    },
                    "weight": city_score
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```